# Is there a word that means "When there's too much of something and people don't take interest anymore"?

Tags: word-choice

For example, there is a new style of shoe, and when there are only a few people who wear it, it's hip and trendy, but now everybody has a pair and it's ______. Or, there's a new and popular product that has a stupid sounding name. It's so popular and the name is said so often that the name doesn't sound stupid any more. The name has become _______.

Comment: commonplace, mainstream

Answer (score 2, accepted):

... but now everybody has a pair and it's [passé:](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/pass%C3%A9)

> ADJECTIVE
>
> [PREDICATIVE]
> 1 No longer fashionable; out of date:
>
> *miniskirts are passé—the best skirts are knee-length*

The name has become a [cliché:](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/clich%C3%A9)

> NOUN
>
> 1 A phrase or opinion that is overused and betrays a lack of original thought:
>
> *In the same way that an overused phrase inevitably becomes a cliché, a recurring joke sooner or later loses impact.*

*or*

The name has become [banal:](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/banal)

> ADJECTIVE
>
> So lacking in originality as to be obvious and boring:
>
> *songs with banal, repeated words*

Comment: Passé is perfect for the first sense, of everyone having fashionable shoes. Doesn't work for the second example, though.

Answer (score 2):

Often people say such a thing is *over-exposed*.

Answer (score 1):

The word you're looking for is blasé:

> **Blasé**: *unimpressed with or indifferent to something because one has experienced or seen it so often before*

Comment: Please remember to indicate the source when quoting references; "Mods are instructed to delete on sight without further warning any content that is not properly attributed." See *[What's up with all these dictionary reference edits?](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/516)* and the linked discussions.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that the thing is saturating/saturated

Comment: This makes no sense: everyone has a pair and they're saturating? Sounds like you get your feet wet. The market can be saturated, but that is a quite different meaning. The shoes can't be saturated, not in the sense you mean.

Answer (score 0):

> What about:
>
> - Familiar
> - [run of the mill](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/run-of-the-mill)

Answer (score 0):

It becomes **commonplace**.

> commonplace
>
> - "something that happens or appears in many places and is not unusual" [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/commonplace)
> - "uninteresting, unremarkable" [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/commonplace)

Answer (score 0):

In order of general popularity:

**Normal**

**Typical**

**Familiar**

**Ordinary**

Answer (score 0):

Pretty cool question:  a single word that has negative connotations for trendy elitists/vocabulary pedants and positive ones for the rest of us.

"Popular" comes pretty close, but it sometimes requires context, because something can be/become popular within a small group/subset of the general population without enjoying widespread popularity / acceptance.

“[Popularized](http://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/popularized),”   on the other hand is more context-neutral, having the notion of “[widespread](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/widespread)” (another option in itself) built right in it (popularized: adjective - enjoying widespread favor or approval) (widespread: adjective: common over a wide area or among many people).

> ...but now everybody has a pair and it's [become] **popularized** / **widespread**.
>
> The name has become **popularized** / **widespread**.

Answer (score 0):

*[Jaded](http://learnersdictionary.com/definition/jaded)*:

> feeling or showing a lack of interest and excitement caused by having
>   done or experienced too much of something
>
> *learnersdictionary.com*

Also *[jaded](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/jaded?s=t)*:

> dulled or satiated by overindulgence
>
> *dictionary.reference.com*

Answer (score 0):

If you're open to paraphrasing, I suggest **fatigue**

From [Oxford](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/fatigue#fatigue) (sense 1.2)

> [WITH MODIFIER] A lessening in one’s response to or enthusiasm for
>   something, caused by overexposure.

Maybe this doesn't fit your example sentences, (words that fit have already been suggested). This fits your title, though. This describes “When there's too much of something and people don't take interest anymore”

For example:

Too many superhero movies may cause ***genre fatigue*** among audiences.

Answer (score -1):

I think Desensitized sums it up pretty well.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this?

Comment: For instance we say people get "desensitized to violence in movies", meaning there is so much that people don't really react to it anymore.

Comment: You should elaborate in your answer - it will stop you getting downvotes.